# Swarms of Codes

Tags: word, knowledge, visual, rebus

Since the days of old, codes have been devised and utilized to various ends: to relay secret messages, to identify friend from foe, or to record secret formulae.

What ancient dark art is at work here?

[image: codes]

Text version:

```
▢▢◯◯▢▢▢ ♂♌︎-()☾☉
▢▢◯◯▢▢▢ ♃♆☉
▢▢▢◯▢▢▢ ♂3♌︎❙☉♃
◯▢▢▢▢▢▢ 25♂☾
◯▢▢▢▢▢▢ ☰8♂☾❘♂3⛰♀☉‍‍☨☾
◯▢▢▢▢▢▢ ☉3♌︎♃♂
◯▢▢▢◯▢▢ /▬♂♃(✸←→)☉
◯▢▢▢◯▢▢ ☾✚♂5☉
```

Hint:

> These tinctures are not to be consumed.

Hint 2:

> 

Comment: It's crazy to see a text version (+1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this one took a while. I was on the right track when it first appeared, but got stuck until the recent second hint confirmed the direction I was going was correct.

So, the short answer first:

> Each line gives us a rebus for the coat of arms of a seven letter country (all but one in Europe), and they are:
>  - Bohemia
>  - Ukraine
>  - England
>  - Croatia
>  - Hungary
>  - Estonia
>  - Moldova
>  - Jamaica
>
>  Lining those up with the grid of circles and squares, and taking the letters in the circles gives us:
>
>  **Heralchemoji**
>
>  Which is a portmanteau of heraldry, alchemy and emoji

## Full explanation

The ancient dark art at work here is:

> [Heraldry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraldry), which uses its own arcane language to describe coats of arms ().
>
>  The hard part was working out the right interpretation of each character, and then translating that into the arcane language of [blazons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazon) in order to look up the correct arms.
>
>  It didn't help that different sources have different blazons for the same arms, which lead to much confusion and head scratching.
>
>   The planetary symbols in particular seem to have multiple meanings, including Sun = gold and Moon = silver. I'm still not sure how to get ♂ (Male/Mars) = red (possibly the red planet?) ♀ (Female/Venus) = green and ♃(Jupiter) = blue.

### 1

> ♂♌︎-()☾☉
>  This is actually the most complex, and one of the last to be solved.
>  The following table give the meaning of each symbol and the heraldic language used (if different from English).
>
> ```
>  ♂        Red                         Gules
>  ♌︎        Lion(Leo)
>         Climbing?                   Rampant
>        Cocktail, knife and fork
>  -()   - cock, knife
>           = Forked tail               Queue fourché
>  ☾        Silver                      Argent
>         Armed
>         Tongued                     Langued
>         Crowned
>  ☉        Gold                        Or
> ```
>
> Which gives us:
>  (Gules,) a lion rampant queue fourché argent armed, langued and crowned Or
>  Which is the [Coat of arms of Bohemia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_the_Czech_Republic)

### 2

> ♃♆☉
>  This one is much shorter and simpler:
>
> ```
>  ♃   Blue            Azure
>  ♆   Trident
>  ☉   Gold            Or
> ```
>
> Which gives us:
>    Azure, a tryzub (trident) Or
>  Which is the [Coat of arms of Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Ukraine)

### 3

> ♂3♌︎❙☉♃
>
> ```
>  ♂   Red                     Gules
>  3♌  Three Lions(Leo)
>     Walking                 Passant
>     Looking                Guardant
>  ❙   In a vertical line       In pale
>  ☉   Gold                    Or
>     Armed                  Armed
>     Tongued                Langued
>  ♃   Blue                    Azure
> ```
>
> Which gives us:
>  Gules, three lions passant guardant in pale or armed and langued azure
>
>  Which is the [Royal arms of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_arms_of_England)

### 4

> 25♂☾
>
> ```
>     Checquered            Chequy
>  25  25
>  ♂   Red                     Gules
>  ☾   Silver                  Argent
> ```
>
> Which gives us:
>  Chequy of twenty-five gules and argent
>
>  Which is the [Coat of arms of Croatia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Croatia)

### 5

> ☰8♂☾❘♂3⛰♀☉‍‍☨☾
>
> ```
>  ☰8  Eight Bars             Barry of eight
>  ♂   Red                     Gules
>  ☾   Silver                  Argent
>  ❘   In a vertical line      In pale
>  ♂   Red                     Gules
>  3⛰  3 peaks                Trimount
>  ♀   Green                   Vert
>     Crown
>
>  ☉   Gold                    Or
>  ‍‍   Family?
>  ☨   Cross of Lorraine/Double cross
>  ☾   Silver                  Argent
> ```
>
> This one isn't a perfect fit. I'm not sure what the family group is for, and there are different descriptions depending where I look for the blazon:
>  Per pale: 1 barry of eight Gules and Argent; 2 Gules, on a mount Vert a crown or, issuant therefrom a double cross Argent.
>  Barry of eight Gules and Argent, impaling Gules, on a trimount Vert a ducal coronet Or issuing therefrom a Patriarchal cross Argent
>
>  But it's still definitely the [Coat of arms of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Hungary)

### 6

> ☉3♌︎♃♂
>
> ```
>  ☉   Gold                    Or
>  3♌︎ Three lions(Leo)
>     Walking                 Passant
>     Looking                Guardant
>  ♃   Blue                    Azure
>     Tongued                Langued
>     Armed
>
>  ♂   Red                     Gules
> ```
>
> Which gives us:
>  Or, three lions passant guardant azure, langued and armed gules
>
>  Which is the [Coat of arms of Estonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Estonia)

### 7

> /▬♂♃(✸←→)☉
>
> ```
>  /   Diagonal to the left    (Bend sinister)
>  ▬   Horizontal              Fess
>  ♂   Red                     Gules
>  ♃   Blue                    Azure
>  (
>    Aurochs
>  ✸   Star                    Mullet
>     Between the horns
>  ←  Rose to the right       Rose to dexter
>  →  Crescent to the left   Crescent to sinister
>  )
>  ☉   All Gold                All Or
> ```
>
> Not sure what the bend is for.
>  Also note that left and right here are from the point of view of the shield bearer, so swapped for the viewer.
>  And that gives us:
>  Per fess gules and azure, an aurochs head cabossed overall, accompanied by a mullet of eight points between the horns, a heraldic rose to dexter and a crescent decrescent to sinister, all or.
>
>  Which is the [Coat of arms of Moldova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Moldova)

### 8

> ☾✚♂5☉
>
> ```
>  ☾   Silver                  Argent
>  ✚   Cross                  Cross
>  ♂   Red                     Gules
>  5  Five pineapples
>     Slipper?               Slipped
>  ☉   Gold                    Or
> ```
>
> This give us:
>  Argent on a Cross Gules five pineapples slipped Or
>
>  Which is the [Coat of arms of Jamaica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coat_of_arms_of_Jamaica)

Comment: Very nice. The associations between the symbols and the rot13(urenyqvp gvapgherf jrer "cbrgvp" naq ner yvfgrq ng uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Gvapgher_(urenyqel). Gur sngure jvgu puvyqera rzbwv va Uhatnel'f oynmba vf fhccbfrq gb ercerfrag gur jbeq "cngevnepuny") Thank you for solving and the detailed answer.